# Control Devices Over the Internet

Tags: c#, sockets, winsock

I want to control devices to remote location using Internet.

I did some Experiments. I have one Laptop connected via WIFI and a computer connected via Router. it works fine. now when i run from system connected to other router it did not worked even both had internet connections.

one reason may be it cannot trace IP because there are many computers. Did implementation done here http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-server-socket.htm

is it possible to control devices over the internet?

secondly what is  difference b/w `Sockets` and `Winsock`?

Comment: Did you configure NTP (port forwarding) on the router at the destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tried your system with wifi and the router I assume you were on the same network. Now you are using the internet you should be using the public IP addresses of your routers and map the port(s) you are using to the specific computers you want the data routed to.  If you do not have static IP addresses available you probably should look into using something like [DyDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) and [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) to create a private network.

As far as your question about Winsock vs Sockets look at this [article](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html)

Edit:  Take a look at this article on [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Comment: how can i have public IP addresses? I have ADSL -> goes to Wifi Router->then other devices

So do i need to have router IP ADSL IP and how to get those?

Comment: what if Client uses Public IP of the Router to which server is connected to point comes that there may be more than one system connected to that router then how come client is going to know which to address?

Comment: the device that your internet plugs into has an IP address it is either a static or a dynamic address. you should be able to look at your routers setup to find out what the address is.

Comment: That is done by mapping the port(port forwarding) you are using to the specific computer you want the traffic to be routed to